# how to make stylish spinner?

Tags: android

I try to create a stylish small width spinner in my `Android` application instead of [default thick spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFZcc.jpg).

I tried to change item's background but then downward arrow disappears from spinner - as on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tVb9.jpg)

How can I get small width spinner?

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/lgnspinner"
  android:prompt="@string/network_prompt"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#000000" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
cityadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```